# How to create a field in access that updates when the rest of the form is filled in

Tags: database, forms, ms-access

Hi stackoverflow community.

I am trying to create an interactive form for my access database, that tries to do as much work as possible for the user inputting the data. We will have to use the form in quick succession with multiple samples so I am trying to automate anything I can.

I have produced the following form at this point, which contains some details about some samples which I will be taking from my upcoming testing.

[image: Snapshot of the form]

What I want to add to the form is a calculated sample name in the "Sample Name" field. This would auto-calculate with data from the other fields and then once the user is finished entering data, its value is entered into the database. For an example, if the sample was from ESN "91014" and from the sampling location "01" and sample type "powder" then the sample name would calculate something along the lines of "91-01-pow". This sample name would then be entered into the database along with its other data. Maybe on the click of a button?

I have tried using the control source section on the property sheet to calculate the value but this doesn't contain the excel functions I am familiar with (left, middle, right etc) and I cant figure out how to code this in VBA.

Has anyone got some experience with this that might solve this?

All the best

Drew

Comment: Saving calculated data is a common topic. It is unnecessary to save this value. It can be calculated when needed. How would you handle if multiple types begin with the same letters? String manipulation functions are definitely available for use in a ControlSource expression. Did you start expression with = sign? If you really must save, then use code in form BeforeUpdate event or a button Click.

Comment: Hi June7, thanks for your help! The sample name would need to be used immediately in order to label the physical samples to identify them. If the samples begin with the same letters I think this would be okay and expected for many, one of the requirements we have of the name is that it allows the sample to be easily identified, not necessarily that it provides a primary key that distinguishes individual samples if you know what I mean? Thanks again

Comment: That doesn't change my comment. Saving to table is not necessary. This value can be calculated in query or textbox or VBA when needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to save the value.

Use this *ControlSource* for the sample textbox to show the sample value on the fly:

```
=Left(Nz([ESN]),2) & "-" & [Sample Location] & "-" & Left(Nz([Sample Type]),3)
```

Comment: Thank you Gustav. This has worked but returns the values of the ID's that I am entering into the table rather than the actual value of the textbox, do I need to add a ".value" to the end of the []?

Comment: Hello Gustav, did you see my above comment? I edited it and I wasn't sure whether you got the chance to see it or not. Thank you again for your help

Comment: You could try renaming the textbox - `ESN` to, say, `txtESN`.

Comment: not much luck I'm afraid, is it to do with the way I set up my comboboxes? I used the wizard to display the ESN but enter the ID into the table. Is there a way of taking the ESN only instead of the ID?

Comment: Yes. Use `[ESN].[Column](n)` where *n* is the zero-based index of the column to retrieve.